# Make @PageableDefault parameters configurable via properties

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

In a Spring MVC controller I want to use default `Pageable` values from a properties file.

```
@RequestMapping
public String list(Model model, @PageableDefault(size = 5, sort = "title") Pageable pageable) {
    // ...
}
```

I tryied to simply write `size = properties.getSize()` but it needs a constant.

How to make `size` and `sort` parameter configurable via properties file?

- Spring 5
- Spring Boot 2

Answer (score 1):

```
 # DATA REST (RepositoryRestProperties)
spring.data.rest.base-path= # Base path to be used by Spring Data REST to expose repository resources.
spring.data.rest.default-page-size= # Default size of pages.
spring.data.rest.detection-strategy=default # Strategy to use to determine which repositories get exposed.
spring.data.rest.enable-enum-translation= # Enable enum value translation via the Spring Data REST default resource bundle.
spring.data.rest.limit-param-name= # Name of the URL query string parameter that indicates how many results to return at once.
spring.data.rest.max-page-size= # Maximum size of pages.
spring.data.rest.page-param-name= # Name of the URL query string parameter that indicates what page to return.
spring.data.rest.return-body-on-create= # Return a response body after creating an entity.
spring.data.rest.return-body-on-update= # Return a response body after updating an entity.
spring.data.rest.sort-param-name= # Name of the URL query string parameter that indicates what direction to sort results.
```

or look for properties [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix)

Comment: Yes but this controls every Pageable object. I want to control this specific one. So I could configure different page sizes for different (website-)pages. Especially there is no way for default sorting.

Comment: Then you can create your own annotaiton which will handle Spel. Just look how `PageableDefault` is handled [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/51e7e1b7f5c9f0161b5b4e1903ea1567d2f260af/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/web/PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.java#L305)